# how to add new custom tab in magento product page

Tags: product, layout, create

I want to know how to add new custom tab on the product view page. Like: Description, Tags, Reviews.
Please give me some suggestion how it will be possible .

Comment: do you have any theme using?

Comment: yes i have use a magento theme

Comment: Give some valuable views

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/layout/local.xml` search tab inside it. You can see something like this

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
```

Duplicate it. Rename description to your desired one. Add corresponding support files in

`catalog/product/view/yourname.phtml`

and

```
 /code/core/Mage/Catalog/block/product/view/Yourname.php.
```

Also you need to change the content as well.

Comment: Custom tab showing but data not showing in the tab.

Comment: what data you need to show? You didnt mentioned in first question..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this in the layout xml file from one of your modules (or `local.xml` of your theme).

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product_info">
        <block type="your_block/alias_here" name="some_name_here" as="some_alias_here" template="path/to/template.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Tab Title Here</value></action>
        </block> 
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then create your block and the template with the content you need.

Comment: Custom tab showing but data not showing in the tab.

Comment: that depends on how your tab block and template look like. I cannot guess what's wrong. You asked how to show a tab and I told you. The tab is shown. So problem solved.

Comment: This does work. Although I had to change `product_info` to `product.info`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it , by creating an attribute. Below i will provide you with a link that i believe it will make clear to you how to solve your problem.

[Add Custom Tab](http://twincreations.co.uk/add-custom-product-tab-in-magento-1-9-ce/)

Check it out.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Single link answers are not the best answer. Please add to your answer at least the significant part of what's found at the end of that URL.